# java.util.zip "can't find the file" error

Tags: java, zip

I'm trying to generate a ZIP with some PDF files in it. The resulting zip is generated and inside there is a PDF file. If I try to open the pdf without unziping it I get a 'File not found' error but if I unzip it and open, then the PDF is properly opened.

```
public byte[] zipBytes(final List<SomeDTO> listDTOS) throws IOException {

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

try {

    for (SomeDTO dto: listDTOS) {

        ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry("Test");
        zos.putNextEntry(entry);
        zos.write(dto.someByteArrayOutputStreamProperty.toByteArray());

        zos.closeEntry();
        zos.finish();
        zos.flush();
    }
} catch (IOException io) {
    LOGGER.error("Error generate zip" + io.getLocalizedMessage(), io);
} finally {
    zos.close();
}
return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

If I open the file directly from the ZIP I get:

[image: Error file not found]

Comment: Why would you expect the API to let you open a compressed PDF file inside a ZIP file without first unzipping?  I'm not surprised by the behavior you are describing.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a Java question. Let me check I've understood properly. You've created a zip file using the Java API. When you then open the zip file in some utility (question: which one?) using Windows Explorer, and you then click on a PDF zip entry, you get an error opening it. Is that correct? Do you also get the same error if you create the same zip file using a third-party utility such as 7-zip or Winzip? If so, then your problem is not related to Java.

Comment: Charles - you need to respond to the comments above.  Otherwise, it is difficult understand what your problem really is ... let alone how to help you.

Comment: Hi sorry for the delay on response I was trying to solve this. The problem was in the baos. I added a baos.close() before returning it and the problem is solved. Now I can open the PDF file directly with no need of unziping it to another folder. Thanks for your hints